# no folders show up using shinyFileChoose R

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a script where I want the user to select a file by browsing with shinyFilesButton. I then want to use the full path of that file as input for a function.

However, when I create a button, no folders show up when I click, just an empty window pop up.

I have previously successfully used ShinyDirButton to select a folder and get the full path. I tried a similar approach for the ShinyFilesButton, however unsuccessful.

What I tried:

```
library(shiny)

ui <-   fixedRow(

   shinyFilesButton("blue", "blue band" ,
   title = "Please select a folder:",
   buttonType = "default", class = NULL, multiple = F)
   )


server <- function(input,output){

  observe({

          shinyFileChoose(input, "blue", roots = c(home = '~'))
          if(!is.null(input$blue)){
            myOutput1 <- parseFilePaths(c(home = '~'),input$blue)
            myblue <- path.expand(myOutput1) #myblue isthen my file path that I can use in my function
            }
          })
         }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If I change `fixedRow` to `fluidPage`. I see the file in my directory `home`. Do you mean you want the different volumes in your system to be shown?

Comment: Both fixedRow and fluidPage kinda work. I can see the directory but I click on one document, I get this Warning: Error in path.expand: invalid 'path' argument

Comment: @SBista I just want to see all my folders and be able to browse through them. It works with shinyDirChoose, but not here.

Comment: @MLavoie thats strange, I didnt get that error, and I use the same command with shinyDirChoose, where there is no problem..

Answer (score 0):

To get all the volumes you need to use `getVolumes()` function  and also add a session object something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <-   fluidPage(

  shinyFilesButton("blue", "blue band" ,
                   title = "Please select a folder:",
                   buttonType = "default", class = NULL, multiple = F)
)


server <- function(input,output,session){


  volumes = getVolumes() 
  observe({

    shinyFileChoose(input, "blue", roots = volumes, session = session)
    if(!is.null(input$blue)){
      myOutput1 <- parseFilePaths(c(home = '~'),input$blue)
      myblue <- path.expand(myOutput1) #myblue isthen my file path that I can use in my function
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!